# Calling a void function in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can I call my function in this data `gridview`? I would like to make the sum of these two to be displayed in the highlighted `datagridview`:

```
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
           datagridview_information.Rows.Add();
           datagridview_information.Rows[counterSelected].Cells[0].Value = row["BrandName"].ToString();
           datagridview_information.Rows[counterSelected].Cells[1].Value = row["GenericName"].ToString();
           datagridview_information.Rows[counterSelected].Cells[2].Value = row["PresDayOfIntake"].ToString();
           datagridview_information.Rows[counterSelected].Cells[3].Value = row["Status"].ToString();
           datagridview_information.Rows[counterSelected].Cells[4].Value = "5";
           datagridview_information.Rows[counterSelected].Cells[5].Value = medicineLeft();
           datagridview_information.Rows[counterSelected].Cells[7].Value = row["ContainerNumber"].ToString();
           datagridview_information.Rows[counterSelected].Cells[8].Value = row["Status"].ToString(); ;
           counterSelected++;
        }
    }
}

public int medicineLeft()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < datagridview_schedule.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
        medleft += Convert.ToInt32(datagridview_information.Rows[i].Cells[8]) - Convert.ToInt32(datagridview_medicine.Rows[i].Cells[4]);
        datagridview_information.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = Convert.ToString(medleft);

    }
    return medicineLeft(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to give more code here, I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to do. Is medleft declared elsewhere?

Your medicineLeft() method is returning itself, meaning it'll run as an infinite loop and will probably throw a StackOverflow exception on this line:

```
datagridview_information.Rows[counterSelected].Cells[5].Value = medicineLeft();
```

Your medicineLeft method needs to return an integer - is it meant to return medleft? If so, changing it to `return medleft;` should fix this.

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution would be to change the way you populate the `DataGridView`. If I were doing this, I would do the following:

1. Create a class object to store the data you want in your grid:

   ```
   public class Medicine
   {
       public string BrandName { get; set; }
       public string GenericName { get; set; }
       <... add other properties ...>
   }
   ```
2. Instantiate a collection of `Medicine` objects that you want to bind to the `DataGridView`.

   ```
   public List<Medicine> GetMedicine(DataRowCollection rows)
   {
       List<Medicine> medicines = new List<Medicine>();
       foreach (DataRow row in rows)
       {
           Medicine medicine = new Medicine();
           medicine.BrandName = row["BrandName"] == null ? string.Empty : row["BrandName"].ToString();
           medicine.GenericName = row["GenericName"] == null ? string.Empty : row["GenericName"].ToString();
           //more rows here to populate Medicine object
           //include the call to whatever methods are needed to populate the object
           medicines.Add(medicine);
       }
       return medicines;
   }
   ```
3. Bind the collection to the `DataGridView`

   ```
   datagridview_information.DataSource = GetMedicines(dt.Rows);
   ```

I find it easy to create the `DataGridView` control on the form, set the columns in the designer, and set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `false` in code so that the grid appears as I wish. It is up to you how you want to handle that.